# CATextLayer not visible

Tags: ios, swift, text, drawing

I have implemented a function to draw the text use of CATextLayer. But after drawing the text is not visible.

Here is my code:

```
func addText() -> CATextLayer{
    let rect:CGRect = CGRect(x: 50, y: 600, width: 120, height: 60)
    let myAttributes = [
                        NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Thin", size:18)!,
                        NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.black.cgColor
                        ] as [String : Any]
    let myAttributedString = NSAttributedString(string: "TEST STRING", attributes: myAttributes)

    let textLayer = CATextLayer()
    textLayer.bounds = rect
    textLayer.string = myAttributedString
    textLayer.position = CGPoint(x:150,y:400)
    textLayer.alignmentMode = kCAAlignmentCenter
    textLayer.displayIfNeeded()
    return textLayer
}
```

Does anyone know the problem?

Comment: Oh my god. I tried for a long time and I have solved the problem by changing textLayer.bounds to textLayer.frame. Thanks.

Comment: It's okay to answer your own question if you think others might make the same mistake. It fits within the intention of what this site is about. I'd suggest either doing that or deleting this question rather than leaving it appearing to all that nobody has answered things. Glad you resolved your problem!